# AS2 - Display game results at end of level

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm currently making a maze game at the minute, and I want to include a death counter and a count-up timer. When the level is over, I want the game to display the time taken and the number of deaths made. How can I make it save the death count, and display it at the end?

Comment: A minimal example of where your current approach is failing would help. What *specifically* is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first frame, declare these two variables which will hold the number of deaths and count up (paste the code on your Frame actions):

```
var deaths = 0;
var time = 0;
```

Now, whenever the player dies, use this code to increase the death count:

```
deaths++;
```

When you want to start the timer, paste this code on the frame where the game begins:

```
function countUp(){
    time++;
}

setInterval(countUp, 1000);
```

This will run the function every 1000th milliseconds, which is the same as every second (1000 milliseconds = 1 second). The function itself increases the *time* variable by 1, but it does not display it on the screen.

Now, on the results screen, you first have to make two **Dynamic** Text Fields (create a text field, open the Properties Panel [CTRL+F3], and change it from Static text to Dynamic text). Give these two Dynamic text fields the instance names of, **death_txt** and **timer_txt**, respectively. Then, paste this code on the frame actions of the results screen:

```
death_txt.text = deaths;
timer_txt.text = time;
```

This will make them show up on the screen.

By the looks of it, it doesn't seem like you're familiar with variables, but they're nothing but containers which contain values. You can control them "behind the scenes", meaning that you can calculate, store and change them in Flash without them appearing on the screen. This is useful since you don't want the death count and count up to actually be shown during gameplay, right?

If you need more clarficiation, please don't hesitate to ask.

Hope this helps :)